# MVVM Light - events on object of model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, light

I have question how to raise events in viemodel on  instance of  model object ?

If I declare the variables directly in viemodel it is easy. just :

```
private bool _something;
        public bool something
        {
            get
            {
                return _something;
            }
            set
            {
                _something = value;
                //do something
                RaisePropertyChanged("something");
            }
        }
```

but what if in viemodel I have :

```
private MyModelClass _projekcik;
        public MyModelClass Projekcik
        {
            get
            {
                return _projekcik;
            }
            set
            {
                _projekcik = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Projekcik");
            }
        }
```

where MyModelClass is  definied in separate file  as :

```
 public class MyModelClass
    {
       int abc {get;set;}
       int other {get;set;}
    }
```

and I  want raise an event  (execute some part of code from viemodel ) when I change value of  Projekcik.abc  ?

For example Projekcik.abc and Projekcik.other are  variables stored selectedvalues from  two comboboxes. And I want raise event to refresh/reload items of second combbbox when user change selected object in first combbbox (when Projekcik.abc are changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `MyModelClass`, and then subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event to do your logic.  E.g.:

```
private MyModelClass _Projekcik;
public MyModelClass Projekcik
{
    get => _Projekcik;
    set
    {
        if(Equals(value, _Projekcik)) return;
        if(_Projekcik != null)
            _Projekcik.PropertyChanged -= HandlePropertyChanged;
        _Projekcik = value;
        if(_Projekcik != null)
            _Projekcik.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;

        void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "abc")
            {
                //Do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you know how to properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.